# I´ve got grid in html file but I can´t see it

Tags: html, grid

I have got this code. But when I try to run this in internet I see just black square. I think that code is right so where can be mistake? Thank you very much.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<title>Title</title>
</head>
<style>
    #board {
        width: 500px;
        height: 500px;
        margin: 20px auto;
        background-color: black;
     }
     #grids {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(20, 1fr);
        grid-template-rows: repeat(20, 1fr);
        height: inherit;
        width: inherit;
     }
</style>
<body>

    <div id="board">
    <div id="grids"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: hi can you try sharing the html code for that?

Comment: Please add the html to the shown css, like @coder mentioned. At best you merge them in a [stack snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do). A good reading would also be https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I haven´t got .css file.  This part of code is from html code and background working good. If I change color from black to aqua for example I see aqua square etc.